# How do I resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java

I am at a very introductory level of programming with java. I am writing a simple code that involves taking an investment and adding an intrest rate into it. The code is not finished yet but I hav run into the *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException* error. Since I am so new to java, I have not yet run into this problem before. Where my confusion comes in is the program will compile. I really don't know how to approach this problem.

As I said I dont have a clue about where to start on this, here is the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CDCalc/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CDCalc.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

The entire code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class CDCalc
{
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int Count = 0;
            int Investment = 0;
            double Rate = 0;


            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("How much money do you want to invest?");
            int Invest = userInput.nextInt();

            System.out.println("How many years will your term be?");
            double Term = userInput.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Investing: " + Investment);
            System.out.println("     Term: " + Term);

            if (Term <= 1)
            {
            Rate = .3;
            }

            else if (Term <= 2)
            {
            Rate = .45;
            }

            else if (Term <= 3)
            {
            Rate = .95;
            }

            else if (Term <= 4)
            {
            Rate = 1.5;
            }

            else if (Term <= 5)
            {
            Rate = 1.8;
            }

            System.out.println("Total is: " + (Rate * Invest));




        }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on this. Thanks

*edit*

I apologize, I should have included this. The code did compile just fine, the problem came in when I ran it. I did use javav CDCalc.java and java CDCalc and thats when the error came up. The even stranger thing is I didn't change a thing, closed out terminal and my text editor, deleted the saved files, reopened everything, saved it, compiled it, and it runs fine now. I apologize again for this post but it seems it fixed itself! –

Comment: 1)  How are you running it?  2)  *Where* are you running it?

Comment: The same code works for me. No problem out there. Check the JRE settings

Comment: Please search first (read: *start with a search*). You are not the first one to run across this problem. I promise.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should compile fine.  The way you compile Java files is different than how you execute them.

You compile with

```
javac CDCalc.java
```

...and run them with

```
java CDCalc
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you tried to run it as `java CDCalc.java`, but it should be just `java CDCalc`.

The Java command takes a class name (not a file name), so there is no ".java" at the end, and no slashes or backslashes but dots for the package name (your class does not have a package).

Comment: I think you are absolutely correct. I didn't realize that in the least! Thank you very much. At least I understand what I was doing wrong. Thank for that!

Answer (score 1):

**This is an sample example:**

```
public class HelloWorldDemo {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println("Hello world test message");
 }
}
```

This is sample hello world program,When i compile this program using javac HelloWorldDemo.java command, this compiles fine and generates HelloWorldDemo.class in the current directory,

After running this programm using java HelloWorldDemo command, I am getting the below exceptions.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassFoundError: HelloWorldDemo

thread main throws this error and exit the program abnormally.

This reason for this error is java virtual machine can not find class file at run time. java command looks for the classes that are there in the current directory, so if your class file is not in current directory, you have to set in classpath, so the solution is to place this .class file in the classpath

classpath is the enviornment variable in every system which points to class files in the directories. if you classfile is in jar file, jar should be in classpath. classpath can be absolute(complete path) or relative path( related to directory )

**solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :-**

HelloWorldDemo.class is not avialble at runtime, so we have to set the class file to java command using -classpath option

**java -classpath . HelloWorld**

This is for fixing NoClassDefFoundError error by setting classpath inline for java command.

We are instructing the jvm to look for the HelloWorldDemo.class in the current directory by specifying .

if class file is in different directory, we need specify the complete directory absolute or relative path instead of . for java command

1. Fix for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in windows:-

To solve NoClassDefFoundError error in windows , we have to set CLASSPATH environment variable.

to set classpath in windows, we have to configure the below values

**set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.;**

%CLASSPATH% means existing classpath to be added and . points to current directory

After setting classpath, 
java HelloWorldDemo
command works fine and prints hello world message

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to add the *current* directory to the classpath manually.  If you ever find that you do, file a bug against Oracle/OpenJDK.

Comment: public class HelloWorldDemo yet you can compile using javac HelloWorld.java ?

Comment: @Bucco Sorry for an mistake,while i am typing i have done a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your program seems fine. Did you compile your java file using `Javac`?

You need to perform steps below:

1. Compiling the `.java` file (source code) using `javac`

   ```
    javac CDCalc.java
   ```

   This should create a class file named `CDCalc.class`
2. Executing the compiled class file using `java`

   ```
    java CDCalc
   ```

Comment: You realize this isn't an answer, right?

Comment: @Makoto I was updating the answer.